# Изменение атритута title выводимой ссылки функции the_author

Tags: wordpress

the_author() выводит ссылку на страницу записей автора в формате

```
<a href="https://my_site/author/my_author/" title="Записи my_author" rel="author">my_author</a>
```

Необходимо изменить атрибут title="Записи my_author" на произвольный

Comment: Это тема обычно выводит. Какая у вас?

Comment: Тема самописная

Comment: Ну так и измените эту строку кода в теме.

Comment: функция выводит тег со всеми атрибутами, уже заполнеными. необходимо поменять на произвольное значение